# What do these function typedefs mean?

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

I am trying to understand what the following typedefs mean. Are they function pointers?

```
typedef int Myfunc(char *);

static Myfunc myfunc;

int myfunc(char *string)
{
    printf("%s\n", string);
    return 0;
}
```

I know `typedef int Myfunc(char *)` means func `Myfunc` return an integer,that's all,all right? And I thought, next statement, how could call `myfunc`?  It should be this way `static Myfunc *myfunc`, mean a function pointer,isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call `myfunc` is the same as a function call:

```
myfunc("a-string");
```

Comment: But how to understand `Myfunc myfunc`? Declare an function variable?

Comment: `Myfunc myfunc` declares a variable called `myfunc` of type `Myfunc`.

Comment: Ok, it seems you are right. But can I could you give me more infomation, a websit or some book ? I want to know more detail.

Comment: The C Programming Language by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie. Search the internet for "C function pointers" should provide you with some helpful information.

Comment: @znlyj, typedef is quite simple. However you define a variable, you write exactly the same thing, with typedef in the beginning and it would become a type instead of a variable. Since `int myfunc(char*)` defines a function (which is actually a function pointer and hence kind of a variable), then with typedef in the beginning it defines a type for functions that look like that!

Comment: It seems like that a function name is a function pointer ,in fact, right?

Comment: You cannot change the address of a function but you can change the address to which a function pointer refers.

Answer (score 3):

The second line is a declaration of a function, not a function pointer. The function is of type `MyFunc`, is called `myfunc`, and has static *linkage*: meaning that the function is not available to other source files compiled into the same object.

Comment: Can I delete `typedef int Myfunc(char *)`?

Answer (score 1):

The signature for the `myfunc` is: `typedef int (*MyFunc)(char *);`
Then you can declare a variable of type `MyFunc` i.e.,

`static MyFunc func_ptr;`

You can then assign a function matching the signature to this variable.

Comment: You mean `typedef int Myfunc(char *)` should change to `typedef int (*Myfunc)(char *)?`

Comment: @znlyj - yes. This means `MyFunc` is a type: `int (*)(char *)`.

Comment: @znlyj, it doesn't compile? Crashes? What errors are you getting?

Comment: No, it compile successfully with `typedef int Myfunc(char *)`. That's why I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's valid code.

```
typedef int (*Myfunc)(char *);
```

declares a type `Myfunc`, that is a pointer to a function that takes a `char *` and returns `int`.

You cannot forward declare a function with a typedef. Omit `static Myfunc myfunc;` and instead begin your function definition with

```
static int myfunc(char *string) {
```

Comment: I read the code from APUE, I think it's valid, but i just don't understand.